# Reporting R Results in LaTeX

Tags: r

I´m writing my thesis in LaTeX (using Overleaf) and I analyzed some data in R. So I have a R script where I perform a bunch of tests and regressions. Now I want to e.g. include the t-statistic and p-value in the Text.

```
x <- rnorm(10, 180, 10)
y <- rnorm(10, 150, 10)
```

Our Hypothesis that x is taller than y was accepted (t =`t.test(x , y)$statisic`; p = `t.test(x, y)$p.value)`.

S.t. In the final pdf it says:

Our Hypothesis that x is taller than y was accepted (t =-7.8841, p = 0.000).

What is the easiest way to do this? What is the workflow?

I`d be thankful for any advice using LaTeX. Even more so for advice for Overleaf.

Comment: I can think of 2 suggestions: `datatool` package if you are willing to save some of the results inside a file and read into your LaTeX code later. Another way is [write18](https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/what-does-write18-mean/)  which you might be able to run a shell command with that. However, if you are using overleaf as a online editor, only the first suggestion might worth trying.

Comment: The `sagetex` package uses open source computer algebra system SAGE which includes R, see [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/r.html). If you don't mind using [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) then you have access to SAGE, which should let you run R, and insert the results into your LaTeX document, similar to my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305764/calculating-descriptive-statistics/305776#305776) which used SAGE but not R in calculating descriptive statistics. Sagetex documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex).

Comment: First page of `sagetex` document says "Similarly,  the  R  statistical  computing  environment  includes  Sweave,  which  lets you do the same thing with R code and LATEX". So maybe worth looking into Sweave. Maybe something like [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Use `knitr` like this: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481061/>

Comment: thanks i made it work with knitr. How can i format what is printed in text. e.g. from scientific totation to normal with 3 decimals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A example code is worth a thousand words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results="hide">>=
set.seed(100)
options(scipen=0)
x <- rnorm(10, 155, 10)
y <- rnorm(10, 150, 10)
accept <- if (t.test(x,y)$p.value>0.05) {print("rejected")} else {print("accepted")}
@
Our hypothesis that $x$ is taller than $y$ was \Sexpr{accept}  (%
t=\Sexpr{round(t.test(x,y)$statistic,2)}; 
p=\Sexpr{signif(t.test(x,y)$p.value,2)}).
\end{document}
```

Save it with the extension `.Rtex` in Overleaf or `.Rnw` if you are using Rstudio. Of course, in this case you should have installed R and the `knitr` package to convert the `.Rnw` file to a true LaTeX file (.tex) and a LaTeX distribution to produce the .tex to .pdf conversion. In any case the result will be:

> Our hypothesis that *x* is taller than *y* was rejected (t=0.76; p=0.46).

Or, replacing "155" by "180" (6th row):

> Our hypothesis that *x* is taller than *y* was accepted (t=8.46; p=3.4 × 10⁷).

Answer (score 1):

It works with the knitr package, in overleaf you dont have to load it.

Everything inside

```
<<echo= F>>=
#Code goes here
d <- read.csv("data.csv")

@
```

is R code. If you create objects in a chunk like this you can print and manipulate those in text with \Sexpr{head(d)}.